# Generate, crop and save images

Tags: php, perl

I am looking to automate a process of:

1. Taking text from a csv and using the value as text for a css button.
2. Capturing that HTML and cropping it so the whitespace is not included
3. Saving the captured button

Steps 1 and 3 are trivial but the problem comes in at step 2. Does anyone know how to take a "screenshot" that targets a specific area of the screen not using co-ordinates or width and height? The images will be variable in width.

I was thinking perhaps it could be based on colour? If a certain colour is encountered at both X and Y then we have an area.

Comment: We have people doing this manually and I'm sure there's a way of automating it. It's "too expensive" to change. Legacy system. :(

Comment: And why not use those buttons - as is?

Comment: That of course would be my preferred approach. The images are referenced within a localisation database so I am also trying a seperate root by including the html as a value.  It's a very large legacy system so changes are very difficult to get past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guess your trying to get images out of this so the best thing I can think of is to use [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [imgmagik](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) to generate them and forget the css or maybe you have a mac an photoshop and can write an applescript to automate the process

Comment: Good point!  I will look at doing it direct with gd or imgmagik.